# Laravel Eloquent elation for pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm currently working on a laravel project, but I'm kind of stuck finding the right eloquent relations.

My tables and the connections (should) look like this:
[Project Relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZP1L.png)

My model relations look like this:

**User**

```
    public function team() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Team::class, 'user_id');
}

public function evaluation() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Evaluation::class, 'user_id');
}
```

**Team**

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function survey()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Survey::class, 'team_id');
}
```

**Evaluation**

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function survey()
{
return $this->hasMany(Survey::class, 'evaluation_id');
}
```

**Survey**

```
public function team()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}

public function evaluation()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Evaluation::class);
}

public function surveyresponse()
{
return $this->hasMany(SurveyResponse::class, 'survey_id');
}
```

**SurveyResponse**

```
public function survey()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
}

public function testquestion()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\TestQuestion');
}
```

Is this the way to go? Do I need a "Has Many Through" relation here? Or a "Polymorphic Relationship"?

Comment: Side note: when you use hasMany in method/relation it is good practice to have it pluralized. I.e. `public function teams() {return $this->hasMany(Team::class);}` Other good practices for naming convention in Laravel you can check [here](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems correct to me, i just didnt see the **TesteQuestion** model (your last relation).

Answering your question:

The **HasManyThrough** relation is just a shortcut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation, in your case:  Users has many evaluations that has many surveys. With this relationship you could get all surveys from a user.

Your relation would look like this:

`/**
     * Get all of the surveys for the user.
     */
    public function surveys()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Survey', 'App\Evaluation');
    }`

You can access this relation like this:

`$user->surveys();`

But you can achieve the same (without using the **HasManyThrough**) by doing:

`$user->evaluations()->surveys();`

Beware that **this will return the evaluations too**, not just the surveys and it requires more processing.

So i **recommend** you doing the HasManyThrough relationship if you pretend to access the surveys a lot.